# Disabling & activating keypress if value false or true

Tags: javascript, keypress

I have a keypress on an input looking like this:

```
$('.input-name').keypress(function(e){
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
        e.preventDefault();
        myFunction();
    }
});
```

If I hit enter myFunction() gets called.

Now I want to check if another value is false or true ... and then deactivate and activate the keypress. How do I do that? The below checks if var is_name is true or false:

```
var is_name;

$('.input-name').on('input', function () {      
    is_name = $('#abcName').val();
    if ( is_name == false ) {
        $('button.filter').attr('disabled','disabled');

        // Deactivate keypress

    } else {
        $('button.filter').removeAttr('disabled');

        // Activate keypress        

    }
});
```

Comment: Stop using outdated stuff like `.keypress`, use `.on` - that has a counterpart `.off`, if you want to remove an event handler again. Or leave the event handler in place, and simply toggle a boolean flag, that the keypress handler then can check when it gets called, to determine whether it should _do_ anything or not.

Comment: Thanks ... can you also provide a working example?

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of state. In your case it is set by `is_name`. If is_name is falsy, pressing enter won’t work and `myFunction` won’t be executed.

```js
var is_name = "";
var
    $nameInput = $('.input-name'),
    $filterButton = $('button.filter');

function myFunction() {
    console.log('Meow');
}

$nameInput.on('keyup', function (e) {      
    is_name = $(this).val();
    // toggles the disabled property
    $filterButton.prop( "disabled", !is_name );
    console.log(is_name + ' is' + (!!is_name ? " " : " not ") + ' valid');
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    // if block won’t be executed if is_name is falsy
    if(keycode == '13' && !!is_name){
        e.preventDefault();
        myFunction();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="input-name" /><button class="filter" disabled>Do something</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle it with [On](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [Off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```js
$(function(){

$("#change_event").change(function(){

  var is_name = $(this).val();

  if (is_name == "true")
  {
    console.log(is_name + " Keypress event Added");
    $('.input-name').on('keypress', function(){ console.log("Keypress event"); })
  }
  else
  {
    console.log(is_name + " Keypress event Removed");
    $('.input-name').off('keypress')
  }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="change_event">
<option value="">Choose</option>
<option value="true">Add Event</option>
<option value="false">Remove Event</option>
</select>

<input class="input-name" />
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I prevent page from reloading if '$('.input-name').off('keypress')' is called? Right now the page reloads which I don't want ...

Comment: Page won't reload because of that?! It will just remove the event.

Comment: Isn’t toggling event listener attachments on every change a little overkill?

Comment: @PhilippM I can imagine your code is wrapped by form elements, isn’t it? This could make the page reload. Then please provide more code to receive help 